# RealityKit – move(to:) methods work only without duration parameter

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit

Using **move(to:)** method to update Entity's position works only if I don't use the the initialiser with **duration** parameter.

```swift
sphere.move(to: newTransform, relativeTo: nil, duration: 0.75) // Absolutely no effect
```

```swift
sphere.move(to: newTransform, relativeTo: nil) // Instant effect
```

Both called from the Main thread. I don't understand what may cause this strange behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Implement `move(...)` method after `arView.scene.anchors.append(scene)`, not before. When you run the following code you'll see that model moves along the +X axis during 2 sec, as expected.

```
let scene = try! Experience.loadBox()
guard let model = scene.steelBox?.children[0] as? ModelEntity
else { return }

var transform = Transform()
transform.translation.x = 0.5
arView.scene.anchors.append(scene)

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    model.move(to: transform, relativeTo: nil, duration: 2.0)
}
```

However, if you do not use the `duration` parameter (i.e. duration = 0.0 sec), the model will instantly move 0.5 m along the +X axis.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    model.move(to: transform, relativeTo: nil)
}
```

Comment: Hey Andy. Thanks for the help. The problem was, as described below, that wrapping the method with @MainActor did not actually trigger a call from the Main thread for some reason. Executing move from DispatchQueue.main.async{} closure did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I've just realised that marking the init method with @MainActor did not cause **move(to:relativeTo:duration:)** to be called on the main thread, executing it within **DispatchQueue.main.async{}** closure did the trick.